# If your housecarl dies, can you get another one?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If My housecarl dies, will I be able to get another one? I need to know because I have mine travel with me everywhere and I pretty much mean everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

If your housecarl, or any other follower for that matter dies in earnest, then they are gone forever (discounting console voodoo).

However, there are [plenty of other followers](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers#Permanent_Followers) that appear depending on where you are in various storylines and you also can gain a [housecarl](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers#Housecarls) for each of the major cities too (indeed for every hold with the Hearthfire DLC), **so yes - you can get another one, but not from the same hold**!

Answer (score 0):

No they are gone for good but for a fee you can hire a follower that will follow you for a set amount of time.  These followers are found on the roads of Skyrim, and usually in taverns such as the drunken huntsman up in Whiterun's middle district.

Comment: Hi, Jon, welcome to Arqade.  I've removed your question from your answer because that's not how we work.  Feel free to ask it as a separate question, but try searching first; maybe someone's already asked it!

Answer (score -2):

The only way to get your follower back when they die is to load an old save.